# What is the difference between face identification, face verification, and face recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition, opencv

I am confused. On some websites, face identification is just face detection, while face verification is finding the person's identification. They are both considered components of face recognition. But in some websites face verification is 1-to-1 matching of faces while face identification is 1-to-k face matching

Answer (score 2):

**Face identification** is the process of **determining** whether a face in a given image belongs to a specific person.

**Face verification** is the process of **verifying** that a given face corresponds to a specific person.

**Face recognition** is the process of **identifying** a person from a given image.

One key difference between face identification and face recognition is that face identification is typically used to determine whether someone is who they claim to be, while face recognition is used to identify people regardless of who they are. Another difference is that face identification is often used as a security measure, while face recognition is more often used for things like tagging photos.

Another difference between face identification and face recognition is that face identification systems often require a person to be looking directly at the camera, while face recognition systems can often work with pictures of people taken from different angles.

Comment: I understand difference between face identification and face recognition but can you explain the difference between face identification and face verification?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do:

1. Find a face (not a specific face) in a frame (I think this is 1-k)
2. <s>Recognition</s> Verification a specific face in a frame (I think this is 1-1)

Comment: I want to know difference between face identification and face recognition.

Comment: identification: There is a face in this picture
verification: It's the face of person P.
recognation: identification + verification

Comment: So, face identification is face detection?

Comment: I don't think it well-defined. It depends on the context you've read this term. I think identification can be slightly more than just detection. Identification could mean to detect a specif group of faces (like a specific ethnicity).
I learned it that way that recognition is to detect if a face is in a frame and to distinguish what face exactly is in a frame.